# How to get the custom email templates list in magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, magento2.3.2

How to get custom email templates list collection in magento2.
how to get the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$alltemplele = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\Collection');
            $alltemplele = $alltemplele->toOptionArray();
print_r($alltemplele_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below code for get email templates :

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  $alltemplele = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\Collection');

  $alltemplele_data = $alltemplele->toOptionArray();;
  print_r($alltemplele_data);
```

i hope its work for you.